# Adding Multiple Images to Sidebar Through Dashboard

Tags: images, sidebar

I have a sidebar with 3 images hardcoded. I'd like to make it so you can change these through the WordPress dashboard.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? Using a plugin, custom post type?

```
<aside id="sidebar">
    <p>
        <img class="img-sidebar" img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/Sidebar1.png" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <img class="img-sidebar" img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/Sidebar2.png" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <img class="img-sidebar" img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/Sidebar3.png" />
    </p>
```

Comment: Code a sidebar widget area and use the native text widget. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143968/9884

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom widget and a custom post type. You can then add your images in the custom post type post, and select that post to display in your custom widget

Answer (score -1):

You should use wordpress plugin for this purpose. [Multi Image Upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/) plugin will be 
   useful for you.

Comment: Please explain **why**

Comment: What does it mean? I simply answer him.